# SyntaxError en reflex init

Tags: python, python-3.7

Estoy intentando crear una página webb, utilizando unicamente codigo python y para ello utilizo el módulo REFLEX.

Siguiento todos los pasos llego al punto de lanzar Reflex init. En este punto me aparecen errores de compilación en los archivos de reflex que se instalan automáticamente. El error que me da es el siguiente caracter  **/,**

He intentado encontrar información en la red pero no he encontrado nada.

Gracias.

> ```
>  **File "c:\users\ususat010\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\reflex\utils\build.py", line 85
>     if (basename= os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(d)))
>                 ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
>
>  `**def __new__(
>         cls,
>         object: Any = "",
>         encoding: str | None = None,
>         errors: str | None = None,
>         /,
>         name: str | None = None,
>     ) -> "LocalStorage":**`
> ```

Comment: Usaste la etiqueta Python 3.7, sin embargo, [la pagina de github](https://github.com/reflex-dev/reflex) indica que reflex es para python 3.8 o superior. Notese que si se mira el código fuente, la parte del fallo usa el operador morsa (agregado en la 3.8). La razón por la que no aparece el ":" del operador morsa en el traceback me es un misterio.